# Using LINQ in Visual Studio while debugging

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2015

**Note:** *I am willing to download and install any extension that may be made for this type of thing. The solution does not need to come directly from standard VS functionality.*

**Question:**
Is there a way to use LINQ or any other querying method to test and view results of a List, Array, IEnumerable, etc... while stopped in the debugger?

I know that you can drop the information contained in an object using the immediate window but I want to know if there is a way that I can sort of build my required LINQ with the actual data.

**Update:**

This is the error I get when trying to use LINQ in the immediate window:

> returnRecords.Select( x => x )
>
> error CS1061: 'List' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no > extension method 'Select'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)error CS1061: 'List' does not

But this works fine in code

> var fu = returnRecords.Select( x => x );

**Update 2:**

Even something as simple as this will not work:

```
        List<int> abc = new List<int>();
        abc.Add(12);
        abc.Add(15);
        abc.Add(16);
        abc.Add(91);
        abc.Add(81);
        abc.Add(14);
        abc.Add(13);
        abc.Add(10);
        abc.Add(145);
        abc.Add(12);
```

immidiate window:

```
abc
Count = 9
    [0]: 12
    [1]: 15
    [2]: 16
    [3]: 91
    [4]: 81
    [5]: 14
    [6]: 13
    [7]: 10
    [8]: 145
abc.Where(x => x < 50);
error CS1061: 'List<int>' does not contain a definition for 'where' and no extension method 'where' accepting a first argument of type 'List<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: With VS2015 you can execute linq queries in the immediate window. You can create and use existing (those available in the scope you are at) variables there

Comment: Most linq queries work in the immediate window/watch window, some DB queries won't

Comment: @Jmaurier - If you better explain what you want to achieve we can assist better

Comment: I usually convert all my linq object(s) to .ToList() so I can easily see the results in a watch window.

Comment: @GiladGreen  I'm not the OP, I was just adding to you comment

Comment: @johnny5 - Oh ops true haha typing error :)

Comment: @Jmaurier - Can you please show what is the code you have to create the resultRecords? If I try it on the collection I created for myself and do on it .Select(x => x) it works fine

Comment: When you are in the immediate window, I believe it will use the context of the code currently executing.  Are you trying it from a spot in code where `System.Linq` is not imported perchance?

Comment: @stephen.vakil 
I'm not going to lie, I don't know how weird the imported libs can get with scope or if the immediate window has any problems with that stuff. But I do know that I have "using System.Linq" at the top where it should be and that I am able to use LINQ on my objects normally -- just not in the immediate window.

Comment: @Jmaurier - It works for me... What version of VS2015 do you have? Under Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your immediate issue is that you are missing a reference to the LINQ assembly in your code; that's why you are seeing the CS1061 error. Just add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file. Then, you will be able to execute the LINQ statements in the immediate window, and you'll see, e.g.:

```
abc.Where(x => x < 50)
{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<int>}
    [0]: 12
    [1]: 15
    [2]: 16
    . . .
```

For more information on debugging LINQ, though, I refer you to two articles that cover it thoroughly:

- Part 1: [LINQ Secrets Revealed: Chaining and Debugging](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-framework/linq-secrets-revealed-chaining-and-debugging/)
- Part 2: [LINQ Debugging and Visualization](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-development/linq-debugging-visualization/)

This is essentially a two-part series (though six years elapsed between the two parts!). The first walks through a variety of ways that you could approach debugging in LINQ, none of which are terribly satisfying, but were about as good as you could get.
[image: LINQ debugging in the early days]

It is still a very useful read, to lay the groundwork of a good understanding of what is involved with debugging LINQ. Then the second article presents the about-to-be-released new capability of OzCode, a Visual Studio extension, that brings full support to LINQ debugging in situ.
[image: LINQ debugging with OzCode]